# How to interpolate a set of points with given local extrema?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, interpolation, education

I have a set of points on the 0xy plane: say

```
(-3,0), (-2,4), (-1,0), (1,2), (3,0), (5,1), (6,0), (8,-2), (10,0)
```

I would like to use software, like Mathematica, to find a curve (say a graph of a polynomial) passing these points such that the curve has local maxima at (-2,4) and (1,2) and local minima at (3,0) and (8,-2).

Do you have any idea to implement it?

Thanks alots.

Comment: `Plot[Interpolation[{{-3, 0}, {-2, 4}, {-1, 0}, {1, 2}, {3, 0}, {5, 1}, {6, 
  0}, {8, -2}, {10, 0}}][x],{x,-3,10}]`?

Comment: Your answer didn't give the imposed local extrema.

Comment: Look into [`InterpolatingPolynomial`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InterpolatingPolynomial.html): it allows you to provide values not only for the function itself, but also for its derivatives, so you can impose the further conditions you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pts = {{-3, 0}, {-2, 4, 0}, {-1, 0}, {1, 2, 0}, {3, 0, 0}, 
       {5, 1}, {6, 0}, {8, -2, 0}, {10, 0}};

poly = InterpolatingPolynomial[pts, x];

Plot[
  poly, {x, -3, 10},
  PlotRange -> All,
  Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point@pts[[All, ;; 2]]}
]
```

[image: plot of the resulting polynomial]